# How to compare two element text in JQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, css

In my project, I am using Jquery. so I have two sections each section have multiple elements with different content, for example, left-content, and right-content. so left-content and right-content have the same class with multiple elements and right-content is dynamic and left-content is fixed one.

so if right-content text and left-content text are equal, then left-content that particular element we have add one new class.

I tried some of the ways but it not working as per my expectations. please help me fix this. if anything is wrong please correct me.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   let headingElement = jQuery('#articleTitle').text();

    jQuery('.ellipsis a').filter(function(){
        return jQuery(this).text() === headingElement;
    }).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active{
  color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="left-content">
  <div class="ellipsis">
    <a href="#">Terminology one</a>
  </div>
  <div class="ellipsis">
    <a href="#">Terminology two </a>
  </div>
  <div class="ellipsis">
    <a href="#">Terminology three</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="right-content">
  <h2 class="heading" id="articleTitle">Terminology two</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: _"I tried some of the ways but it not working"_ - _'"It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it.'_ (Source: [mcve])

Comment: Since you are using jQuery, you could combine your `headingElement` variable into the `.ellipsis a` selector, instead of running `filter()` using [contains](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/). Which would simplify things quite a bit.

Comment: _"if right-content text and left-content text are equal"_ - Is it enough when e.g. _"Terminology one"_ is anywhere in `.right-content` or is the position relevant? So if it is at index 1 in `.left-content` it also has to be at index 1 in `.right-content`?

Comment: @andreas Thanks for your suggestion. if anything is wrong with my question sorry about that. I am saying left content is heading and right content is a description and this data coming from JSON file. Click on the heading this data will change. but if heading and description both are same I have to add a class in heading content. that's it.

Comment: @DBS thanks for your help. but contains can't compare with the element. it just compares fixed string. but mine the content will change based on user click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood your task correctly.

Was such a result necessary?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
let headingElement = jQuery('#articleTitle').text();
  jQuery('.ellipsis a').each(function(){
    if (!$(this).text().indexOf(headingElement)) {
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.active{
  color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="left-content">
  <div class="ellipsis">
    <a href="#">Terminology one</a>
  </div>
  <div class="ellipsis">
    <a href="#">Terminology two </a>
  </div>
  <div class="ellipsis">
    <a href="#">Terminology three</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="right-content">
  <h2 class="heading" id="articleTitle">Terminology two</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your help. yours also working fine.

Comment: @sankar, no problem. glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:contains` this will check if the element has required text or not then addClass to that element.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  let headingElement = jQuery('#articleTitle').text();
  jQuery('.ellipsis a:contains(' + headingElement + ')').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="left-content">
  <div class="ellipsis">
    <a href="#">Terminology one</a>
  </div>
  <div class="ellipsis">
    <a href="#">Terminology two </a>
  </div>
  <div class="ellipsis">
    <a href="#">Terminology three</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="right-content">
  <h2 class="heading" id="articleTitle">Terminology two</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: thank u so much. it's working fine. I tried using contains but I used to like this- ('.ellipsis a:contains('headingElement ')').